# Check all products belong to a category are enabled or disabled?

Tags: ruby-2.3, rails-4-2-1

I have products belongs to a category and each product has status enabled and disabled `enum status: [:disabled, :enabled]`. On Category page I want to check weather all products in category all enabled or not.

I tried below code which return array with `true` or `false` of each product

```rb
c = Category.find(1)
c.products.map{|p|p.enabled?}
```

With raw mysql query it's possible. But as newbie to rails want to know how to get it done using rails code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do
`enabled = c.products.size == c.products.enabled.size`
`enabled` will return `true` or `false` based on all products status enabled or not

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23670977)

Comment: I elaborated my answer